# NodeJS: One Global EventEmitter or every module it's own?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, events

I am currently planning to create a browsergame in NodeJS. The Game will use events for basicly every communication between the modules.

### What is more performant (or has advantages or disadvantages?):

I use only one (global?) EventEmitter. Every module can listen to that global event stream or emit events in the global event stream. I would use more complex event-names, so when an event is fired, not all listeners on the global event stream are called. I have a really high amount of listeners on one single event stream.

Example: Player1 receives an item. The event "player1:inventory:item" is fired, and only player1 listens on that event on the global event stream.

### OR

Every module on it's own extends the events.EventEmitter and provides only the events for that specific object. The number of listeners on every EventEmitter is very low, most of the time there is only one listener.

Example: A single player has a questlog and an inventory. For every player I create an instance of questlog and inventory, hold them in a collection (or the player object). The questlog of player1 ONLY listens on the inventory of player1.

---

I don't have experience with the EventEmitter in NodeJS and only know that there is a warning when there are more that 10 listeners on one eventemitter or event because of memory leaks, but I don't know why.

I see some advantages and disadvantages on both systems, but on the technical side I need advice.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what eventing style or mix of event styles you're using in your application. If you're using a broadcast style where multiple subscribers subscribe to a channel/topic and multiple publishers publish to that channel/topic, then the EventEmitter instance has to live in something that's "global" to its publishers and subscribers. With the broadcast style, neither the publishers nor the subscribers need to have knowledge about each other.

If your eventing is more point-to-point style where each subscriber subscribes to a publisher which it has a reference to, then the subscriber has to know about the publisher and the subscriber has to have been instantiated before the publisher.

Both styles can be implemented by either the global singleton EventEmitter (using event namespaces) or by the per module EventEmitter, but the global EventEmitter is a more natural fit for broadcast style, and the per-module EventEmitter is more natural for the point-to-point.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think extending Eventemitter for your module is definitely better. You'd do it like this. It's a common pattern of module writers.

```
 var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
 var util = require('util');

 function YouEmitter() {
     EventEmitter.call(this);
 }
 util.inherits(YourEmitter, EventEmitter);
```

There are a lot of reasons to do this, but little resources with hard fact background. One very good probably is this one by Mozilla's [Node Holidy Season Series](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/).

> 1. You may not be worried about your increasing memory footprint, but V8 is. (V8 is the engine that Node runs on.) As leaks grow, V8 becomes increasingly aggressive about garbage collection, slowing your app down. So in Node, memory leaks hurt performance.
> 2. Leaks can trigger other types of failure. Leaky code can hang on to references to limited resources. You may run out of file descriptors; you may suddenly be unable to open new database connections. Problems of this sort may emerge long before your app runs out of memory and still leave you dead in the water.
> 3. Finally, sooner or later, your app will crash. And you can bet it will happen right at the moment when you’re getting popular. And then everybody will laugh and say mean things about you on Hacker News and you’ll be sad.

Apart from Garbage Collection, random failure of other components, I think the last point is the most interesting: It's probably bad style. It makes your app heavy weight, when Node is the the opposite.

Also calling callings constructors is very expensive.

Another reason is that debugging memory leaks and related failures isn't trivial to debug (judging from what I see on SO).
When eventemitter leaks, it really goes ballistic since it's blocking the event loop.

A lot of other event based libraries like [Seneca](http://senecajs.org/) and [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) allow their event clients to receive all emitted events. They'll determine whether their should be an action by pattern for example whether the payload of the event is interesting to them or IDs match etc.

Distinguishing by event name is probably the easiest in your case (something like this):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();

var eNR2 = '2';
ee.on('event'+ eNR2, function(){ console.log('Event 2 has fired!')});
ee.emit('event2');
```